# Referencing a .net 4.6. csproj in asp .net 5 class .xproj issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop, dnx

I have a. net 4.6 class library with the wrap folder configuration which includes the project.json which is configured to point to the compiled `bin/obj/[output] .dll` and `.pdb` files and the `global.json` in the `.csproj` root.

This was configured automatically via adding the `.csproj` reference in the asp. net 5 class project.

However the local package folder in `c:\user\\.dnx\packages` is not being created thus the output states:

> the package could not be found

I am using the beta7 release version of dnx.

**Things I have tried**

I have tried running `dnu restore` from the command line with the same output result.

I have updated to the latest beta 7 web tool for vs 2015 and updated to the latest dnvm.

Comment: I had a similar issue - https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2991

Comment: Thanks I also  chimed in there with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by manually adding the reference to the wrapped csproj into the global.json of the .xproj.

I also posted this finding into the git issue listed in the comment in the op.

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test","wrap","../hldotnet_lib_hlenums/wrap" ],
    "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x86"
    }
}
```

**Update**

Nevermind it still is having issues resolving dependencies, using a workaround by generating nuget packages of the projects and reference them that way for now.

Comment: yeah we use the nuget method as well but we would prefer the above way.

Comment: I do hope that part of dnx gets resolved soon and a little more seamless, right now it involves a lot of under the hood tinkering.